# Question on a maximum likelihood estimator is chi-square distributed with degree of freedom n-k

Tags: calculus, self-learning, regression, maximum-likelihood, regression-analysis

The same question which I asked previously. But I did different solution from the previous one. I solved this by using given hint.

Previous question and solution are this:
[Question on maximum likelihood estimation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520226/question-on-maximum-likelihood-estimation)

Question:

[image]

My new answer is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please check my solution. I am really not sure about this solution. And please tell me my mistakes and missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems right, just note that $X$ is not a square matrix, hence
$$
(X'X)^{-1}\neq X^{-1}(X')^{-1},
$$
however you result still holds as
$$
tr(X(X'X)^{-1}X')=tr(X'X(X'X)^{-1})=tr(I_k)=k.
$$

Comment: Okay thank you for you to check my solution.